# How to POST an Object that contains a String list from AngularJS to ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following javascript object:

```
var param = {
  FilePaths: ['String1', 'String2', 'String3'],
  Share: false
}
```

My AngularJS POST is the following:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: config.apiUrl + '/ImportSubset/Import',
  data: param,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

My ASP.NET Controller:

```
public class ImportSubsetController : Controller
{
  public class ImportParam
  {
    public List<string> FilePaths;
    public bool Share;
  }

  public JsonResult Import(ImportParam param)
  {
    (...)
  }
```

When I call my Import API the `Share` property passes just fine but the `FilePaths` is `Null`. What am I doing wrong here? I tried with `data: JSON.stringify(param)` but still passes as `Null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Add the below class FilePaths-**

```
public class FilePaths
  {
    public List<string> Path { get; set; }

  }
```

**2.Mention The FilePaths , as a property in the ImportParam class-**

```
public class ImportParam
  {
    public FilePaths filePaths { get; set; }
    public bool Share { get; set; }
  }
```

**3.Decorate your json as below, and assign this to  param variable-**

```
{
  {"ImportParam":{

 "filePaths":{"Path":["String1","String2","String3"]},

  "Share": false}}
}
```

Comment: Adding the '{ get; set; }' to my 'ImportParam' class.fixed the problem. Thanks